# AngularJS ng-if call function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use `ng-if` call function to get the text data, but I don't know why the `ng-if` is don't work and it prints all text data. Please help. Thank a lot.

I try to only use the `ng-if` is work

http://jsfiddle.net/grm7cy2x/1/

This is the use `ng-if` call function code

http://jsfiddle.net/g8p2x70f/51/

Comment: Please do not include only links to your code. Copy/paste the relevant code in to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that what you return from `checkValidDataType` is treated as a string, it's not evaluated as a piece of code anymore. In other words this is how it's seen:

```
< ... ng-if="'data.partment == 2 || data.partment == 3 '">
```

(note the single quotes there)

To understand it better, you can try something like

```
< ... ng-if="'cat'">
```

Any non-empty string is true in JavaScript, therefore the strings that you return from your functions always return true (just like a string `'cat'`, that's why ng-if renders every radio button.

In order to solve this, you can write your code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in records">     
  <div ng-if="checkValidDataType(1, data)">       
    <input type="radio" name="{{data.name}}" value="{{data.value}}">
    {{data.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$scope.checkValidDataType = function(someValue, data){
     if(someValue == '1')
         return data.partment == 1 || data.partment == 2;
     else if(someValue == '2')
         return data.partment == 1 || data.partment == 3;
    else
        return data.partment == 2 || data.partment == 3;
 }
```